# Getting the most accurate precision with a function equating factorial, divison and squaring

Tags: python, probability

How can I get the best precision in an equation involving factorial, division and squaring?

As an example, I'm trying to make the binomical probability calculator in python:

```
# n: Number of trials
# X: Number of successes
# p: Probability of success on a single trial   
def binominal(n, X, p): 
    return ( math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(n - X) * math.factorial(X)) ) * ((p**X) * ((1-p)**(n-X)))

print(binominal(5, 1, 0.166666666666))
```

Output:

```
0.4018775720164609
```

Now comparing with the binomial probability gained from an [online calculator](https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx):

```
0.3468305983
```

My precision is way off. How can I get a better precision? I looked at the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) and then tried to use the `Decimal` form instead, I didn't really get a better result from that.

Comment: I'm getting `0.40187757202` from the online calculator.

Comment: Same here, `0.40187757202` from the online calculator. It looks like your code runs correctly.

Comment: The main thing to watch out for here is that intermediate quantities such as n! can overflow even if the final result won't. Try computing the logarithm of the binomial instead -- note that log(n!) is a simple summation. There might be a built-in function for the logarithm of the gamma function (remember n! = gamma(n + 1)).